# Could not find driver ( PHP and Firebird )

Tags: php, xampp, ubuntu-14.04, firebird, firebird2.5

I have a web-based PHP script named `portail`, so I want to make it functional on **Ubuntu**.

I installed **Xampp 5.6** , **Firebird 2.5** under **Ubuntu**, then I uncommented the library:

```
"extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll"
```

and I made the specific configuration for **php5** and **firebird**
(https://mapopa.blogspot.com/2009/04/php5-and-firebird-pdo-on-ubuntu-hardy.html),
but he always shows me the following message

> could not find driver localhost/portail

**Screenshot:**

[image: Could not find driver ( PHP and Firebird )]

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu, then you cannot use `extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll`. DLLs are for Windows, not for Linux. Try with `extension=php_pdo_firebird.so`, and verify that extension actually exists. You may also want to consider posting your question to the firebird-php mailinglist.

Comment: Thank you Mark for your response, unfortunately I don't have extension=php_pdo_firebird.so in php.ini

Comment: Then add it. If you're really on Ubuntu, then `extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll` cannot work (and should never have been present in the first place, which might indicate other problems with your setup).

Comment: I agree with you, but when I installed xampp from the official site I don't find extension=php_pdo_firebird.so in the first place just extensions (.dll).

Comment: unforunately I tried all the solutions to install pdo_firebird but the problem still the same.

Answer (score 4):

You should install the required php extension if not already installed by default installation process. Php extensions are binaries which help php do extra things which can not without them. For example there is another well-known php extension called `X-Debug` which helps php developers debug their code.

First of all check that you have this `php_pdo_firebird` extension installed (or not), using Ubuntu CLI (Command-Line Interface):

1. installed system-wide by default:

   ```
   php -m | grep -i pdo-firebird
   ```
2. installed using your package manager:

   ```
   dpkg --get-selections | grep -i php-pdo-firebird
   ```

If none of the above returned a result, then you do not have that extension installed. you should install it using your preferred package manager:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y php-pdo-firebird
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I made all the instructions step by step and I installed the extension php-pdo-firebird again but it shows that I can't install this extension.

Comment: That is another question and you would better ask it on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
php -v
apt-get install -y php<your php version>-interbase
```

Comment: if you have a specifc version of PHP add after php and before -